# How to fix error with checking error in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, error-handling

I have a code fragment like this:

```
(...).catch(e) => {
         if(e.response.status === 401) {
          console.log("Wrong username or password")
       } else {
           console.log(e.statustext)
}}
```

And I have error like this: `Unhandled Exception (TypeError): cannot read property status of undefined`

How can I fix it?

Comment: can you `console.log(e)`  and see what it is, presumably `response` doesn't exist on the `e` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`catch` block is passed an [Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) object and it doesn't contains any property named `response`.

Inside the `then()` block, check if status code is 401, if it is, throw an Error with the message `"Wrong username or password"` and inside the catch block, log the message using [Error.prototype.message](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/message)

```
.then(response => {
    if (response.status === 401) {
       throw new Error("Wrong username or password");
    }
    ....
 })
 .catch(e) => console.log(e.message));
```